# How to get selected text on a DropDownList Yii2 widget?

Tags: php, arrays, drop-down-menu, yii2, widget

I'm trying to get a text selected from a DropDownList into my model but I keep getting the "index" value of de DropDownList (if I select the second item I get a 1).

I have an array like this:

```
Array ( [0] => some [1] => array [2] => for [3] => example )
```

And I try to get the selected text into the 'field' attribute of my model like this:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'field')-> dropDownList($array, ['prompt' => 'Select something']) ?>
```

The thing is that when I get my posted data in my controller I get the selected value (property) not the selected text. Lets say that I've selected 'example' then I get a '3' in my post variables. How can I get the selected text instead of the index-like value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use value as key with the help of [array_combine()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php):

```
$array = [0 => "some", 1 => "array", 2 => "for", 3 => "example"];
$array = array_combine($array, $array);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/SpDHU)

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [some] => some
    [array] => array
    [for] => for
    [example] => example
)
```